# Finding max of a list of Maybe values in Haskell using Higher Order Functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, option-type

I am trying to use higher level order functions to take a list of Maybe values and return a max of type int but for some reason I can only return a Maybe value.
For example this works:

```
max' iL = foldl maxMaybe Nothing iL
maxMaybe Nothing  y = Just y 
maxMaybe (Just x) y = Just (max x y)
```

However this doesn't as it says it still expects a Maybe value but it is generating an int for a result:

```
max' iL = foldl maxMaybe (minBound::Int) iL
maxMaybe Nothing  y = y 
maxMaybe (Just x) y = (max x y)
```

Comment: I recommend writing out all of the type signatures of the top-level functions. This often improves GHC's error messages and it also makes it easier to think about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second implementation you use wrong type for accumulator, because the `foldl`'s accumulator is the first argument of its function - here is `maxMaybe` function-, we have to swap arguments in `maxMaybe`:

```haskell
max' :: Foldable t => t (Maybe Int) -> Int
max' = foldl maxMaybe (minBound::Int)

maxMaybe :: Ord a => a -> Maybe a -> a
maxMaybe y Nothing = y
maxMaybe y (Just x) = max x y
```

this function now works, but I think this method is not good way for finding the max value and I prefer the first implementation, because you can do pattern matching on result of it.

I suggest to change the first implementation to this one, becauseas `foldlr` is preferable for haskell [foldr](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27#Foldl) and `Just (Just a)` is redundant and ugly:

```haskell
maxWithFoldlr = (Foldable t, Ord a) => t (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
maxWithFoldlr = foldlr maxMaybe Nothing

maxWithFoldl :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
maxWithFoldl = foldl maxMaybe Nothing

maxMaybe :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maxMaybe Nothing  y = y 
maxMaybe x Nothing  = x
maxMaybe (Just x) (Just y) = Just $ max x y
```

Comment: Finding the maximum element in a collection should be a strict fold with an accumulator - so `foldl'` for lists. `foldr` will just waste a lot of stack space unless the optimizer realizes you wrote bad code and fixes it for you. Unfortunately for pedagogical purposes, GHC is actually pretty good at that.